# Javascript issues *New to programming*

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run this code I get the following:

```
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

at startup (node.js:119:16)

at node.js:902:3
```

I have no prior experience with programming or Javascript but I'm excited to learn. Any Input is appreciated ^_^

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
}
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
}
else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
}
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: You have not actually told us what the error is. What you posted just shows *where* it was.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that there's no function called "prompt".

Comment: `prompt` is a JavaScript method available in web browsers. It's not available in Node.

Comment: Please don't downvote beginner questions. Let's encourage, not discourage.

Comment: @Matt Yes, but also don't sympathy-upvote them because of the rep imbalance.

Comment: @bjb568 how is a rep imbalance bad?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score

Comment: @bjb568 I don't see how that applies here. This question is perfectly valid on SO and deserves to be answered, but was downvoted because it wasn't asked as ideally as it could have been. Beginners often don't know how to ask questions, it's not something we should hold against them but help them with. Not to mention a question downvote does more damage than the "sympathy" upvote can repair, the opposite of the situation in that meta question.

Comment: We're talking about the reputation problem, not how invited OP thinks (s)he is to the site. This is not a perfectly valid question, this is a code dump question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasted anyone's time. Thanks Matt, Pointy & @Jackson for helping me figure out this problem. It shows me that I have a lot more to learn.

Comment: @bjb568 I'm sorry man, but it's attitudes like yours that are exactly why SO sucks these days. It's gotten so damn anal here most have forgotten the point is to help people. A little question like this won't get much attention and won't "harm" SO at all in the grand scheme of things, but this pervasive anal attitude that is so common now is exactly what will drive newbies away from programming.

Comment: @Christopher It's fine. Everyone starts as a beginner. If you haven't already, you should see the [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @Matt You don't seem to understand downvotes. A downvote means "this post has questionable-quality content, an edit may help". When it gets improved, it will receive upvotes. People who downvote are not evil. If you really want, you could leave this site since your attitude doesn't seem very positive.

Comment: @bjb568 It's true, my attitude is not so positive at SO anymore. It's because I've watched this site degrade into what it is now over the past 4 years. I disagree that is what downvotes are for, they are generally for "this is a waste of SO's time, don't focus on it". Comments are a much better place to suggest people improve their questions, especially since most downvotes are not explained. How can anyone possibly know what to do to improve their question when the only feedback they've received is "-1"?

Comment: @Matt Explanations [are encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/237813) for downvotes. If somebody doesn't leave an explanation, too bad. They don't have to. If you want to, that would be great! Saying "the community doesn't look at downvoted content" is wrong. Most views come from Google or the home page, neither of which are affected by voting. Many times I will **specifically find bad posts** to improve, not everyone thinks it's just a waste of time. You seem to, which is just the wrong attitude for SO. If *you* think that downvotes are bad, they will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prompt()` (actually `window.prompt()`), is not availabe in the Node.js environment. Use Node's "readline" module instead.

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?", function(answer) {
  // code to handle the answer goes here
  rl.close();
});
```